# Characterization of $n^{-1} max_{1 \le k \le N} Y_k \to 0$ in probability for $Y_n$ i.i.d.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am a beginner in probability and am currently having trouble with 
the following problem:

> Consider $Y_n$ i.i.d. random variable. Find a necessary and sufficient condition for $n^{-1} max_{1 \le k \le N} Y_k \to 0$ in probability.

As a shot in the dark, I am attempting to show that 
the condition holds if and only if $E(Y_n^+) < \infty$.

I was able to show that $E(Y_n^+) < \infty$ if and only if $n^{-1} max_{1 \le k \le N} Y_k \to 0$ almost surely.
Thus, I am hoping that I would be able to show that
if $n^{-1} max_{1 \le k \le N} Y_k \to 0$ in probability, then $E(Y_n^+) < \infty$.

My attempt is the following:

By way of contradiction, suppose $E(Y_n^+) = \infty$.
Then, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(Y_n^+ > n \delta) = \infty$.
Since $\{Y_n^+ > n \delta\} = \{ Y_n > n \delta\}$ and $Y_n$ are independent, 
by Borel-Cantelli Lemma, $P(Y_n > n \delta \text{ i.o.} ) = 1$.
From here, I am stuck.

I am not sure if I am trying to prove the right condition to begin with. 
Any advice/hint would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** Notice that $P[\max_{1 \le k \le n} Y_k < n\varepsilon] = P[\cap_{1 \le k \le n} Y_k < n\varepsilon ] = P[Y < n\varepsilon]^n$ by independence. Thus, looking at the complementary events we have
\begin{equation}
P[\max_{1 \le k \le n} Y_k \geq n\varepsilon] = 1 - (1 - P[Y \geq n\varepsilon])^n.
\end{equation}
To deal with the absolute value, we can write
\begin{align}
P[|\max_{1 \le k \le n} Y_k| \geq n\varepsilon] 
  &= P[\max_{1 \le k \le n} Y_k \geq n\varepsilon] + P[\max_{1 \le k \le n} Y_k \le -n\varepsilon] \\
  &= P[\max_{1 \le k \le n} Y_k \geq n\varepsilon] + P[\min_{1 \le k \le n} (-Y_k) \geq n\varepsilon] \\
  &= 1 - (1 - P[Y \geq n\varepsilon])^n + P[-Y \geq n\varepsilon]^n
\end{align}

Comment: This is not quite correct, you can't pull the absolute value into the Maximum.

Comment: @Dominik Thanks for the correction